# Unable to display jpg img in grid (tml)

Tags: image, jakarta-ee, src, tapestry

I have an object Resource with an attribute picture.

If in my grid I do:

```
<p:pictureCell>
    <img src="${context:/css/images/pic.jpg}" width="110" height="80" />
</p:pictureCell>
```

I can display the picture. But if I try to get it from the object I can't

```
<p:pictureCell>
    <img src="${resource.picture}" width="110" height="80" />
</p:pictureCell>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Hi could you paste a stack trace or include the grid tag in your code snippet as well? And is resource.picture a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the response to my problem:

I have to do:

```
<p:pictureCell>
    <img src="${context:}${resource.picture}" width="110" height="80" />
</p:pictureCell>
```

I hope it helps somebody